# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable but object is not nonetype

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def winner(board):
    WAYS_TOWIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                  (3, 4, 5),
                  (6, 7, 8),
                  (0, 4, 8),
                  (2, 4, 6),
                  (0, 3, 6),
                  (1, 4, 7),
                  (2, 5, 8))
    for row in WAYS_TOWIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != " ":
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
    if " " not in board:
            return TIE
    else:
        return None



#Main
instructions()
human = input("Enter your name: "); print("\n")
pieces = who_first(human, computer); print("\n")#pieces becomes a list with human piece first and computer piece second
board = new_board(); print("\n")
winner = winner(board)



while winner == None and winner != TIE:
    if turn == pieces[0]:#if human is first
        winner = winner(board)
```

> When I run the winner function the first time, it returns none to the winner variable and there are no errors. But when I run it for the second time it gives me TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. The board is a list with [" "]*9 and i dont get why calling the board the second time is a nonetype  object.

Comment: You have a variable named `winner` and a function named `winner`. See the problem?

Comment: @Aran-Fey why would that create an error?

Comment: @Pris_code because everything is an object and we don't want two objects with the same name in the same namespace. As soon as you "assing" something new to a name (variable, function, class, whatever) it gets overwritten.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I get what you're saying, but do you mind just explaining in this context what is happening specifically to the winner objects.

Comment: Not sure what needs to be explained. The function object is being replaced with `None`.

Comment: @Pris_code This is the same as writing
`a = 2` then `a = 'example'` 
and expecting to get `2` next time you use `a`

Comment: Related/dupe: [Recursive function: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable](//stackoverflow.com/q/28466965)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I see now thank you mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you run `winner = winner(board)` winner becomes `None` therefore on the second call it's not calling the function but `None` hence the Error. Changing the names will solve the problem, it's not recommended to use same variable name and function name.